# gstreamer: streaming using x264, rtph264pay and depay

Tags: gstreamer, h.264, rtp

basically I was trying to get this thing working.

```
gst-launch v4l2src ! videorate ! 'video/x-raw-yuv, framerate=30/1' ! \
x264enc ! rtph264pay ! gstrtpjitterbuffer ! rtph264depay ! \
ffdec_h264 ! xvimagesink
```

...but I always get very **low framerate** and this **error**:

```
gstbasesink.c(2875): gst_base_sink_is_too_late (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstXvImageSink:xvimagesink0:
There may be a timestamping problem, or this computer is too slow.
```

Obviously I get the same error even if I try to udpsink the stream and using udpsrc in another instance of gst-launch.

What's wrong with my pipeline?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

Add to `xvimagesink`: `xvimagesink sync=false`. Otherwise it will be polling for a new frame all the time.

`udpsink` also does have a `sync` parameter.